# Read a fille based based on a path derived from the column of another file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have this is tsv file in Azure Data Lake which contains two main columns among other columns:

| Id | ResponsePath |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | response path for id 1 |
| 2 | response path for id 2 |

The response path for each record is a path to json file which is a also stored in Azure Data Lake.

I want to iterate over each record in the file, read the json stored in the file using the response path for that record, extract a property from this json and add it as a column along with the data from original file tsv file and upload this output to another data store.

So the end result would look something like this:

| Id | ResponsePath | trace id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | response path for id 1 | 61sd3414e |
| 2 | response path for id 2 | 6153eidkl |

How do I do this is Azure Data Factory?

I tried setting up a lookup to fetch the column but the I cannot query for files in ADLS under the lookup module. I was thinking about using some data flow but have no idea how to set it up for this purpose since I would have to create a source based on a coulmn from another file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Lookup activity** to read the `tsv` file and then use **foreach** activity to iterate over each row in `tsv` file.  Inside foreach activity, use dataflow activity to get the field value from Json by passing the `ResponsePath` as a dataflow parameter.

[image]

- In Dataflow, take the source transformation (source1) and read the file from the dataflow parameter.
- Take the flatten transformation and derived column transformation to flatten the Json and fetch the data from the Json file.
- Using derived column transformation, create a new column and store the `ResponsePath` value in that.
- Take another source transformation(source2) and read the data from `tsv` file.
- Take the join transformation and join source2 and derived column transformation output basis the `ResponsePath` column
- Take only required columns from the join transformation using **Select Transformation**
- Then take the sink transformation with the same dataset of source2. This will make sure when next iteration is running, data from json will be inserted in the same file.

**Dataflow inside the For-each activity:**
[image]